# Warning: Private methods cannot be final as they are never overridden by other classes during compilation

Tags: magento2, installation, third-party-module, custom-theme, third-party-plugin

I successfully installed the Martfury-Marketplace Magento theme. Subsequently, I executed the command 'php bin/magento setup:di:compile', however, an error occurred as follows:
[image]

Therefore, I fixed the issue by adhering to the following guide:-
[Deprecated Functionality: Optional parameter $data declared](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/359253/deprecated-functionality-optional-parameter-data-declared)

After fixed it,
[image]

I re-executed the command 'php bin/magento setup:di:compile' but, another error occured as follows:
[image]

Info.php on line 83
[image]

Section.php on line 164
[image]

Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty obvious you have an issue of declaration with one of the method of your module Magefan Community. Setting the method public or removing the static should fix the issue.
Provide the code and we might help more than that.

Comment: hello sir, can you tell me any solution for this problem ? how to setting the method public ?

Comment: well...by replacing private by public

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience, sir. Despite changing the declaration from private to public and after run the compile command, I am encountering an issue where the module is missing from the server.But, compilation completed successfully.

Comment: @Hirun Did you enabled the module ? bin/magento module:enable Vendor_Name ? Is it present in your config.php ? Is it present in the setup_module table ?  What does your error says exactly now ?

Comment: It's okay sir. I changed the magento version and now it appears to be working properly.